# Replace all occurences of a string in data frame without disturbing the original structure

Tags: r

```
> str(test)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ name: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
 $ var1: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ var2: Factor w/ 1 level "x": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ var3: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 $ var4: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ var5: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> test
  name var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    a    a    x    1    a    1
2    a    a    x    2    b    2
3    a    a    x    3    c    3
4    b    a    x    4    d    4
5    b    a    x    5    e    5
6    b    a    x    6    f    6
7    c    a    x    7    g    7
8    c    a    x    8    i    8
9    c    a    x    9    j    9
```

I am going to replace all occurrences of pattern `"a"` with pattern `"ABC"` of data frame `"test"`.

```
> test[] <- lapply(test, gsub, pattern = "a", replacement = "ABC", fixed = TRUE)  
> test
  name var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1  ABC  ABC    x    1  ABC    1
2  ABC  ABC    x    2    b    2
3  ABC  ABC    x    3    c    3
4    b  ABC    x    4    d    4
5    b  ABC    x    5    e    5
6    b  ABC    x    6    f    6
7    c  ABC    x    7    g    7
8    c  ABC    x    8    i    8
9    c  ABC    x    9    j    9
> str(test)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ name: chr  "ABC" "ABC" "ABC" "b" ...
 $ var1: chr  "ABC" "ABC" "ABC" "ABC" ...
 $ var2: chr  "x" "x" "x" "x" ...
 $ var3: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ var4: chr  "ABC" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ var5: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Now `str` of the data frame has been changed to `character` type for all data type , however, before replacement it was in `factor`,`int`,`numeric`.

The dataset is huge and original dataset has hundred of columns with a different data type. How do we do the replacement without disturbing the original structure of the data frame?

Comment: Are you doing the replacement only for factor columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the `levels` of the column and update it

```
test[] <- lapply(test, function(x) {
                      levels(x)[levels(x)=="a"] <- "ABC"
                        x})
test
#  name var1 var2
#1  ABC  ABC    x
#2  ABC  ABC    x
#3  ABC  ABC    x
#4    b  ABC    x
#5    b  ABC    x
#6    b  ABC    x
#7    c  ABC    x
#8    c  ABC    x
#9    c  ABC    x




str(test)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ name: Factor w/ 3 levels "ABC","b","c": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
# $ var1: Factor w/ 1 level "ABC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# $ var2: Factor w/ 1 level "x": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

If the match is a partial match

```
test[] <- lapply(test, function(x) {
                      i1 <- grepl("a", levels(x))
                      levels(x)[i1] <- "ABC"
                        x})
```

---

If there are columns that are numeric, character class etc, create a index of 'character', 'factor' class and change the values only for those

```
i1 <- sapply(test, class) %in% c('factor', 'character')
test$var1 <- as.character(test$var1) # for testing
test[i1] <-  lapply(test[i1], function(x) {if(is.factor(x)) {
             levels(x)[levels(x)=='a'] <- 'ABC'
               } else x[x=='a'] <- 'ABC';
             x})
```

Comment: Thank you akrun ,  structure unchanged only for factor , however structure has been changed to  "atomic" for rest  like "int" ....could you please help to fix this as well

Comment: @Maverick  Could you please change your example to a more representative example.

Comment: @Maverick  I updated the post.  Please check if that helps